# Как правильно оформить эпиграф и подпись под ним?

Tags: пунктуация

> *Кто привык взирать на мир как историк, тому знакомо это чувство глубокого счастья, когда для взора вещи вдруг ясно предстают, пусть и
>   не полностью, но в своих истоках и в своем изменении, когда сущее
>   освобождается от случайного облика и позволяет познать себя в качестве
>   ставшего, необходимо свершившегося. И чтобы испытать это чувство,
>   нужно обладать чем-то еще, помимо планомерного обозрения…*
>
> Генрих Вёльфлин «Объяснение произведения искусства», 1921 г.

Как сделать втяжку вправо (в тексте письма)?

Главное мне подпись, какие там знаки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мильчин даёт следующие рекомендации:
1. Выравнивание по левому краю, но сам эпиграф расположен в правой части страницы (делается увеличением отступа), только подпись выравнивается по правому. Абзац есть.
2. Кавычек нигде нет, точка в подписи не ставится (но у Вас сокращение года, так что она будет).
3. У него (Мильчина) в примерах текст обычный, подпись — курсив.

Comment: А что со знаками в подписи: ***Генрих Вёльфлин «Объяснение произведения искусства», 1921 г.*** - такого ж быть не может!

Comment: Есть пример с точкой после автора, название работы без кавычек. Года в этом примере нет, но, думаю, можно указать в скобках или запятую оставить.